# Error message when running an executable created by pkg.. How would you solve it?

Tags: node.js

Steps..
0. I used @nut-tree/nut-js

1. pkg index.js (tried to create an executable using pkg)
2. ran index-win.exe in another directory to test..

It does not seem to find some files.

I tried to add this to package.json file.
"files": [
"./node_modules/@nut-tree/**"
]

That did not help..

This is the error message I get

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1833
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\build\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\build\Debug\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\build\Release\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\out\Debug\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\Debug\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\out\Release\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\Release\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\build\default\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\compiled\16.14.2\win32\x64\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\addon-build\release\install-root\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\addon-build\debug\install-root\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\addon-build\default\install-root\libnut.node
 → C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\libnut.node
    at bindings (C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut-win32\index.js:1:97)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1887:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1812:31)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at C:\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules\@nut-tree\libnut\index.js:4:11 {
  tries: [
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\build\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\build\\Debug\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\build\\Release\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\out\\Debug\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\Debug\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\out\\Release\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\Release\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\build\\default\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\compiled\\16.14.2\\win32\\x64\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\addon-build\\release\\install-root\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\addon-build\\debug\\install-root\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\addon-build\\default\\install-root\\libnut.node',
    'C:\\snapshot\\streamlabs-api-demo\\node_modules\\@nut-tree\\libnut-win32\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64\\libnut.node'
  ]
}
```

Note :
line 4 of :\snapshot\streamlabs-api-demo\node_modules@nut-tree\libnut\index.js: return require(`@nut-tree/libnut-win32`);

Answer (score 0):

im a little late but try including

```
  "bin": "./index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": "index.js",
    "assets": ["node_modules/**", "node_modules/@nut-tree/libnut-win32/build/Release/*"],
    "outputPath": "exece"
  },
```

in your package.json
then run pkg . -t host